# How to find optimal solution

Tags: graphics, mathematical-optimization, numerical-value, maximum

I want to ask something. Right now, I want to try to find the optimal solution from a function in a paper. here is the function :

[image]

[image]

And here is the numerical example :
[image]

There is solution procedure that is written on the paper like this :
[image]

So I assume, I have to run the function with different value of n 1 by 1 until I found the optimal solution. But when i try to run the function there is an error : FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value f[1.] is not a real number at {s} = {1.}.
Here is what I wrote on mathematica :

```
Clear["Global`*"]
L = 4;
w = 0.064;
d = 2;
R = 250;
Kf = 750;
cf = 0.1;
m = 0.2;
Kp = 500;
hp = 0.05;
Kd = 100;
h = 0.1;
g = 6.87;
q = 0.12;
a = 80;
b = 0.2;
pv = 1;
pf = 2;
pr = 5;
x = 0.9;
n = 1;
z = 120;
E = 0.2;
F[s_] = pr/s ((a*(1 - b)*(2 L s - s^2))/(2 L))^(1/(1 - b)) - (pv w)/(
   s x d) ((a*(1 - b)*(2 L s - s^2))/(2 L))^(1/(1 - b)) - Kd/s - Kp/(
  n s) - Kf/(
  n s) - (h a*(1 - b))/(
   2 L s)*{s + (((1 - b)/(
         2 - b))*(2^(1/(1 - b)) L^(1/(1 - b)) s^((2 - b)/(1 - b))) + 
       s^((3 - b)/(1 - b)))} - 
  hp/(2 R s) ((a*(1 - b)*(2 L s - s^2))/(2 L))^(2/(1 - b)) - (
   hp (n - 1))/(2 s) ((a*(1 - b)*(2 L s - s^2))/(2 L))^(2/(
   1 - b)) {s*((a*(1 - b)*(2 L s - s^2))/(2 L))^(1/(1 - b)) - 1/R} - (
   cf x + m E)/(s x d) ((a*(1 - b)*(2 L s - s^2))/(2 L))^(1/(
   1 - b))*{g n s + g/q (Log[1 + z E^(-q n s)] - Log[1 + z])}
Plot[f[s], {s, 400, 1200}]
FindMinimum[f[s], s]
```

Note : I change some symbol in the function i write in mathematica.

[image]

This is what it look like in mathematica (I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to attach mathematica file directly here):
[image]
[image]

Can you help to explain to me what I did wrong and what I'm supposed to do?
here is the paper link in case it was needed : [Paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0307904X20306120)

Comment: You can't use `E` as a variable name - this is the built in symbol for the exponential constant. Also, your function is `F` and you're trying to plot `f`. Also `s` is undefined.

Comment: You cannot use `{}` to group code in Mathematica. Change those to `()`, You define the function `F[s]` and then try to plot `f[s]` Mathematica is intensely case sensitive. Your function is complex for some values of `s` Try `Plot[ReIm[F[s]], {s,0,15}]` The complex values may mean you have more problems that must be found and fixed before trying to find the minimum.

Comment: The function "f[s]" is complex. Do you need the absolute value?

Comment: @DanielHuber, i'm sorry for asking since i'm not that good in english, but does absolute value means positive value? If yes, than I do need absolute value since i need to find the optimal solution of s (or T in the paper) which is replenishment time. And the value of replenishment can not be negative.

Comment: @Bill, I've tried it but got negative answer {-598.886, {s -> 1.}}. In the paper, the optimal solution of T is 1.62 when the value of n is 20. But when i try to change the value of n to 20, it also give negative result {-1.70707*10^6, {s -> 1.}}. Is there is something i'm supposed to do first?

Comment: Absolute value of a complex number is always a positive number or zero.

Comment: If I change all `E` to `e`, all `{}` to `()`, `F[s_]=` to `F[s_]:=`, `n=1`, `Plot[f[s],{s,400,1200}]` to `Plot[F[s],{s,1,8}]` then I see a nice minimum near `s==6` and I tell it to look starting near 6 using `FindMinimum[F[s],{s,6}]` and it returns `{-484.697,{s->5.681}}` approximately. If I change `n=1` to `n=20`  then I see a nice minimum near `s=4` and I tell it to look starting near 4 using `FindMinimum[F[s],{s,4}]` then it returns `{-3.792*^7,{s->4.000}}` approximately.  Since your `F` grows so big so fast, I must tell it to begin very near the minimum. Can you EXACTLY duplicate ALL this?